# Select specific result only from multiple results and combinations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following simple query:

```
SELECT
  Company.Company_Name,
  Company_Team.Team_Role_Recid
FROM
  Company
  INNER JOIN
  Company_Team ON Company_Team.Company_RecID = Company.Company_RecID
```

The values for Team_Role_Recid  can be:

```
1, 2, 3 or NULL
```

Or a combination. There can be 1 and a 2, or a 2 and 3, or just a 2, or nothing at all, etc. You get the idea.

I want to always list every Company_Name result, but only show Team_Role_Recid if it is a 1, otherwise have it replaced with ‘None Assigned’.

I’ve tried various methods in a where clause, even attempted a sub-query, using CASE WHEN in the select statement for the 'None Assigned' change with no luck.

Cheers

[EDIT]

I may not have been as clear as possible. I'll add this in to try and make it clearer.

I need to list the Company and the Team_Role_Recid if it is 1. If the Team_Role_Recid is anything other than 1, it needs to say 'None Assigned'.

```
CompanyName      TeamRecID

Company A        1
Company B        None Assigned
Company C        None Assigned
Company D        1
Company E        1
Company F        None Assigned
```

A Company can have a Team_Role_Recid record of 2, or just 3, or 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 in the database, etc, but I want to display it as above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead, and `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values:

```
SELECT a.Company_Name,
       COALESCE(b.Team_Role_Recid, 'None Assigned') RecID
FROM   Company a
           LEFT JOIN Company_Team b
               ON b.Company_RecID = a.Company_RecID 
-- WHERE  b.Team_Role_Recid = 1
```

Comment: With COALESCE returning the first non-null result, what if the first result is a 2?

Comment: Then it will return 2 because COALESCE  will just simply replace the null values with your desired value

Comment: In that case, although this answer gets me closer, it doesn't do what I need. I only want to display 1 if b.Team_Role_Recid = 1, else 'None Assigned'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.Company_Name,CASE WHEN isnull(b.Team_Role_Recid,0) = 1 then b.Team_Role_Recid else 'None Assigned' end
FROM   Company a
       LEFT JOIN Company_Team b
       ON b.Company_RecID = a.Company_RecID
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Can you pls give me your source table with sample data,i will try to get the results.

Comment: Hey just try updated query...I just used ISNULL there.Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
Declare @Company table(Company_Name Varchar(50),Company_RecID int)
Insert Into @Company 
Select'Company1', 1 Union All Select 'Company2', 2 Union All 
Select 'Company3',3 Union All Select 'Company4',4

Declare @Company_Team table(Company_RecID int,Team_Role_Recid Varchar(10) null)
Insert Into @Company_Team 
Select 1,1 Union All 
Select 1,2 Union All Select 1,3 Union All Select 2, Null Union All
Select 3,1 Union All Select 4,2 Union All Select 4,3


;with cte as(
SELECT
  c.Company_Name,
  ct.Team_Role_Recid,
  status = CASE WHEN ct.Team_Role_Recid = 1 then '1' else 'None Assigned' end
FROM  @Company c
LEFT JOIN  @Company_Team ct ON ct.Company_RecID = c.Company_RecID )

Select distinct Company_Name,Team_Role_Recid from (
SELECT Company_Name,Team_Role_Recid FROM cte WHERE Company_Name NOT IN (SELECT Company_Name FROM cte WHERE status='None Assigned')
Union All
SELECT Company_Name,'None Assigned' FROM cte WHERE status='None Assigned')x
```

### Result

**Company_Name  Team_Role_Recid**

```
Company1    None Assigned
Company2    None Assigned
Company3    1
Company4    None Assigned
```